# CSS Centering container divs

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I am trying to center two divs in a container div but it is not working.   I have text-align center but that does not work. I also had a HTML center tag but that also did not work. Any ideas?

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
      display:block;

  text-align: center;
}
#left {
  float: left;
margin-right: 30px;
width: 70px;

  text-align: center;

}

#right {

float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70px;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
        One:
      <p>
        <button onclick="plus" id="6">plus</button>
        <p>
        <button onclick="minus" id="7">minus</button></div>    

        <div id="right">
        Two
        <p>

        <button onclick="plus2" id="6">plus</button>
        <p>
        <button onclick="minus2" id="7">minus</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float`

Comment: @Alex Thanks, that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left;`

Also you can group selectors to avoid repeating same styles.

```css
#wrapper{
  display:block;

  text-align: center;
}
#left, #right{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70px;
}
#left {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="left">
    One:
  <p>
    <button onclick="plus" id="6">plus</button>
    <p>
    <button onclick="minus" id="7">minus</button></div>    

    <div id="right">
    Two
    <p>

    <button onclick="plus2" id="6">plus</button>
    <p>
    <button onclick="minus2" id="7">minus</button></div>
</div>
```